# My audio output or input does not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have these two types of port for headphone or microphone but none of them are working. I am using ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS.

[image: audio ports 1]

[image: audio ports 2]

Here is what it's showing inside pulse audio.
[image: pulse audio settings]

Comment: You want to select the analogue output, not HDMI nor S/PDIF.

Comment: @ChanganAuto there is no other option except HDMI optiom